# what to figure out before creating a DB design?

Tags: database-design

i am new to web development and my manager has assigned me shopping cart project, i am ok in programing. But, i don't know how should i start DB design for any project, what should be my approach for BD design of any project, how should i think in that direction and what things i should figure out before creating a DB design, how i should think of entities and relation between them...please elaborate me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, figure out all the entities that you want to represent, such as customers, carts, products and so on.

Then work out what attributes you want for each. For example, a customer will have an ID, name, address, shipping address and so on. Carts will consist of a customer ID and multiple products. Don't be *too* concerned about missing out details here since they can be added later.

The assignment of attributes to your entities will almost certainly put the relationships between those entities into your mind. That's the next step, to figure out the relationships between all your entities.

Once you (think you) have all that, run through a few use cases (new customer, customer adding things to a cart, checkout/payment and so forth). This may turn up things which you didn't think of and you can adjust your entity/relationship diagrams to suit. *Document* these use cases and add to them as needed, they'll be invaluable when it comes time to finalise the schema.

And remember, no matter what, start with a third normal form database schema. It's okay to revert to lesser forms for performance (provided you understand and mitigate the issues involved in that) but that's something that comes *much* later and *only* if you have a real performance problem with 3NF.

Third normal form means that every non-key column in a table depends on the key, the *whole* key and nothing *but* the key.

---

By way of example, here's a basic schema to get you going:

```
   +--------------------+        +-----------------+
   | Products           |        | Customers       |
   +--------------------+        +-----------------+
+->| ProductId (pk)     |        | CustomerID (pk) |<-+
|  | Description        |        | Name            |  |
|  | StockLevel         |        | Address         |  |
|  | Cost               |        | ShippingAddress |  |
|  +--------------------+        +-----------------+  |
|                                                     |
|  +--------------------+        +-----------------+  |
|  | CartContents       |        | Cart            |  |
|  +--------------------+        +-----------------+  |
|  | CartID (pka,fk)    |------->| CartID (pk)     |  |
+--| ProductID (pkb,fk) |        | CustomerID (fk) |--+
   | Quantity           |        | Status          |
   +--------------------+        +-----------------+
```

That allows for four fairly basic entities and you can add more, it depends on what you need. You may want to handle special offers for bulk buys, loyalty programs, and other things. The status in the cart contents would be `initial`, `paidfor`, `payment confirmed`, `shipped`, `received` and so on but you may want to use a separate `orders` table once a cart has gone through the checkout process - I've kept it as simple as possible.

It also allows for multiple carts per customer, a feature I find very annoying when it's not there (in other words, please implement this, there's nothing more annoying than having to clear a cart you've already set up to do another transaction you want processed first).

Comment: Sir a very thanks to you for this help, its clear to me how should i proceed. Sir what is pka and pkb ?

Comment: sir i am not clear with the CartID in the CartContents and Cart.are they both auto-increment field or they both are separate than that of identity key? So identity key should also be there ?

Comment: CartID is just a unique identifier for the cart. _How_ you generate it is an implementation detail. Most likely, it would be an auto-increment on the Cart table but you would then use that _specific_ value to populate the CartContents table.

Answer (score 2):

This is way too broad a question. But i suggest you check  [this out - Database Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_design) especially "*The Design Process*" section

```
Determine the purpose of your database - This helps prepare you for the remaining steps.
Find and organize the information required - Gather all of the types of 
information you might want to record in the database, such as product name 
and order number.

Divide the information into tables - Divide your information items into major
entities or subjects, such as Products or Orders. 
Each subject then becomes a table.

Turn information items into columns - Decide what information you want to 
store in each table. Each item becomes a field, and is displayed as 
a column in the table. For example, an Employees table might 
include fields such as Last Name and Hire Date.

Specify primary keys - Choose each table’s primary key. The primary key 
is a column that is used to uniquely identify each row. 
An example might be Product ID or Order ID.

Set up the table relationships - Look at each table and decide 
how the data in one table is related to the data in other tables. 
Add fields to tables or create new tables to clarify the 
relationships, as necessary.

Refine your design - Analyze your design for errors. 
Create the tables and add a few records of sample data. 
See if you can get the results you want from your tables. 
Make adjustments to the design, as needed.

Apply the normalization rules - Apply the data normalization rules
to see if your tables are structured correctly. 
Make adjustments to the tables.
```

Also, make sure you get it reviewed by someone who has a bit more experience in designing databases

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends heavily on your particular needs. As a starting point, why not download some open source shopping cart apps (like [Dashcommerce](http://dashcommerce.org/) or [aspdotnetstorefront](http://www.aspdotnetstorefront.com)), and analyse their database design? They might even fit your needs and you won't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: SteveCav has a good suggestion.  If you will be using SQL Server take a look at the database design of the AdventureWorks database.  While it does not have a table named "Cart" there is a order header and detail talble.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to develop a shopping cart if you are new to database design? Go get an off-the-shelf solution or find someone with the expertise to help you.